# Python error: IndexError: list index out of range (Google trends data)

Tags: python-3.x, google-trends

I have to get google trends data from a list of KEWYWORDS.
I'm used to analyze data with STATA and this is my first time that I'm using Python (via project jupiter notebook).
I cannot do it via STATA since it doesn't have a package to download google trends data. It seems that Python it does via "pytrends"
Here my codes

```
pip install pytrends
import pandas as pd
import pytrends
from pytrends.request import TrendReq
pytrend = TrendReq()
KEYWORDS['GYMM','GYNE','GYNX']
KEYWORDS_CODES=[pytrend.suggestions(keyword=i)[0] for i in KEYWORDS]
```

Here I have this problem
"---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
----> 1 KEYWORDS_CODES=[pytrend.suggestions(keyword=i)[0] for i in KEYWORDS]

in (.0)
----> 1 KEYWORDS_CODES=[pytrend.suggestions(keyword=i)[0] for i in KEYWORDS]

IndexError: list index out of range"

I run the codes one by one and this messagge appears when I type the last line of codes. Just to be honest, I found this code on a web guide for those interested in taking Google trends Data (unfortunately since I don't have a knowledge on Python I'm not able to build my own code).
Actually my keywords are copy and paste from txt file (Here I wrote few of them, nevertheless they are thousands)

Would you be so kind to give me some suggestions?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result of `pytrend.suggestions(keyword='GYNX')` (the third item in your list) is an empty list `[]`, so indexing it via `[0]` returns the `IndexError`

Comment: Thank you for your kindly answer. So, should I put the number of keywords inside [], rather than [0]?

Comment: Hi Marco, I think you should just use `pytrend.suggestions(keyword=i)` without the index so that if there isn't an error when there are no keywords returned by the function

Comment: Thank you for you suggestion. I removed it and now it doesn't show any error.
Nevertheless, on the left side of the line command I have this notation [*]
As far As I know for jupiter notebook it means that is running the code but not completed. Now it has been one hour, do you think that it might be for my many keywords that I have to run the search?

Comment: Yes I think that means that the code is still running, another indication would be that there is an egg timer symbol in the address bar